# JD Edwards REST API with Request response JSON

Tags: java, rest, jdedwards

We are working on customer project, where customer has got JD Edwards Enterprise One. Their installation supports REST API ( I tried defaultConfig API and it worked.)

Usually in REST API, developer shares API signature in terms on GET params or Request/Response JSONs, while in case of JDE E1 documentation they have shared Java Code (that to in fragments).  Its really hard to construct req./resp. based on the code snippets.

Will appreciate if anyone has worked on similar activities and guide.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53430_01/EOTRS/index.html

I don't like to answer with a link, but I can't possibly paste all of the (current today, but not tomorrow) REST API documentation for JD Edwards EnterpriseOne.

Here is a sample of what the service documentation looks like:
[image: Example REST API documentation for JD Edwards EnterpriseOne]

Answer (score 2):

**We can use REST API's for JD Edwards using the AIS Server**

This API's provides us various services to interact with JD Edwards system.
To give a brief idea onto same:

- JD Edwards consist of Reports and Application, so using the Rest API's you can call the Applications, perform actions onto them e.g,
  button-click, typing text into text-boxes or grids, reading the data
  from grid or text-boxes etc.
- We can also call the JD Edwards reports using this API's.
- It also provides us services to Upload and Download Media Object.

**We can use the API's by two ways:**

1. Directly using the plain JSON Request: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53430_01/EOTRS/index.html
2. Using the AIS Client Java API
   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24705_01/doc.91/e62368/ais_java_ovrvw.htm#EOTJC107

**JD Edwards also provides Orchestrator for easily accessing this API's**.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53430_01/EOTOT/understand_iot.htm#EOTOT107

Using this Rest API can be challenging for a person not from JD Edwards background. It would be easy to understand this API Implementation if you have worked on Oracle MAF and JD Edwards Integration.

**Third custom approach for Rest API's with JD Edwards**
We can build the Rest API's in any programming language (Java, .NET, Python etc.) and expose the JD Edwards Database tables to it.